# Is it possible to connect do remote desktop with windows azure websites?

Tags: azure, iis-7.5, remote-desktop, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I have been doing this with webrole. But as I understand windows azure websites: multiple sites hosted in a single webrole.

Q.1. Is it possible to connect to webrole?

Q.2. Is it possible to atleast connect to Azure IIS management console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, with Windows Azure Web Sites it is a managed solution. You can edit web.config and use the management portal, but there is no more direct ways to access the underlying compute resource.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Jeff's answer, while you can't remote debug your website, you can terminal connect to it by going to the `scm` endpoint of your site: `http://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net` and selecting "Debug console".

More on this here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console

It will give you a nice way for managing some aspects of your site (mainly file based) but will not let you do other things like install office for example.