# Is it possible to install software in a VMs where an app is deployed in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have read how Azure App Service Plans works and I have found that an app which runs in a basic, standard or premium tier, is hosted on dedicated Azure VMs. Now I have a question, Is it possible to access to the operating system of the Virtual Machine to install any software I need? For Example a driver(.exe) or something similar

This is the site where I have found the information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the correct site for information. Although App Service may not be the right Azure offering to to try and install 3rd party software on. You should probably consider using something else like a Virtual Machine, Virtual Machine Scaleset or Cloud Services.

Look at these references -

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d991c03-713f-4035-87d2-7aa0685a527d/how-to-install-a-third-party-software-in-app-service-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

[Can we RDP / install third-party software to Azure App Service Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121219/can-we-rdp-install-third-party-software-to-azure-app-service-web-app)

Only App Service plan where something might be possible is the App Service Environment plan which is a high cost premium option meant for running apps that require very high scale and isolated secure network (even ASEv2 came out recently), because it offers dedicated environment. So maybe there is some possible way and might be worth checking further. 
Although, as you can see the intent of App Service environment is also very different, so more probably than not you should be looking at other Azure offerings for your requirement.