# how to install azure cli on azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I have been using azure cli installed on windows 7 locally. I want to use it on azure web app as well. But I did not find any relevant article to accomplish it. Could anyone let me know how to install az-cli on azure web app windows instance.

Thanks

Comment: why? you dont really need azure cli there

Comment: my backend api needs it to create resources using az cli.

Comment: this means you need to use azure sdk, really, not azure cli

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create resources from your code you should use the Azure REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

It also has client libraries, you can read more about it on the link.

Comment: No I need az cli as I am using commands like ```az bot publish```, ```az bot prep-publish```.

Comment: Ok, you did not mention this in your question. Can't you do this with the bot framework rest api?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Here is a related question about installing software on WebApp, based on this you won't be able to install any app on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121219/can-we-rdp-install-third-party-software-to-azure-app-service-web-app