# Is it possible to install c++ compiler in azure app service

Tags: c#, c++, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have azure app service on Windows and I want to install c++ compiler on it.
I need the c++ compiler to compile and run c++ code runtime. The user submit some code(console application) I compile it and then run it with different inputs. I run command like `g++ file.cpp` for compilation and `file.exe` in cmd using `Process` class in c#.

Is there a way to connect remotely to my azure app service and install the c++ compiler? Or are there some other ways to install c++ compiler on azure app service?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot install software (like your compiler) in an Azure App Service. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36185208/1537195

You would need to go to something like either your own container (see for example [Azure Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker) or Azure Container Instances) or host your custom code inside a VM.