# Azure Private Endpoint: Disable RDP, Set TLS version?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-private-link

We are using private endpoints with our Azure App Service. We have seen that you can RDP to a private endpoint address, and the private endpoint supports TLS 1.0.

Does anyone know how to disable RDP and set the TLS version?

Comment: What is behind the private endpoint you’re RDP’ing to? My understanding is that a private endpoint itself is not a resource that would support such a setup. In other words: just because there is a DNS record for a domain somewhere doesn’t mean that there’s anything there to RDP to.

Comment: That was my thoughts as well, at the end is an Azure App Service, but if you try RDP to the private endpoint you get tge Username and password prompt

Comment: Can you link to an authoritative source which states that you should be able to RDP into an Azure App Service resource? The answers on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121219/can-we-rdp-install-third-party-software-to-azure-app-service-web-app) seem to state that this should not be possible.

Comment: Sorry, what we have seen is we can open a rdp session to the endpoint address and we are trying to workout how to disable this

Comment: Can you share a bit more information on how your private endpoint is configured, possibly a screenshot or two from the Azure portal? I just spun up a brand new instance of an App Service and cannot successfully get a username/password prompt to spawn on connecting with RDP - I'm not sure the private endpoint you're referencing is pointing to the resource you believe it is, but I can't be sure until you edit your question to include some more information about what the endpoint is actually pointing at/how it is configured.

Comment: Thanks, I will do in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service, by design, does not include any resources into which you can connect with Remote Desktop.

To set the minimum TLS version for your App Service, you can use the Azure portal. Navigate to your app service -> TLS/SSL Versions and select the minimum version which you'd like the service to support:

[image]